# How can I add add a site to Baidu webmaster tools when I am not in China?

Tags: seo, baidu

I have a site and want to submit it to Baidu console but unable to do so.  How can I do that with step by step process?

I already tried with by Indian contact number but I've been unable to create a Baidu account. Is there any process to create a Baidu account with an Indian phone number?

Comment: The interface is all in Chinese and they want a chinese phone number to verify your account.    I'm not sure it is worth it to verify your site from outside china.  Here is a a site that lists the steps with English instructions:  http://www.dragonmetrics.com/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-baidu-webmaster-tools/

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a trick to create Baidu Account.

1. Connect to Hong Kong VPN
2. https://login.bce.baidu.com/?lang=en use this link to create Baidu account without Chinese mobile number

I found this to be 100% working.